# Get a single field from a subdocument array in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Below is my collection schema...

What I am trying to do is get the value of **"eak"** from **"Website 1"** and use it in my application. I am struggling to pull the value out of the multi embedded array.

```
_id:1234,
role:"client",
organization:"My Organization",
email:"myorg@notarealemail.com",
password:"myEncryptedPassword"
websites: 
[{
    _id:5554
    name:"Website1"
    wak:"567567567"
    wid:"5678"
    preview:"aSweetImage"
    cid:"678"
    integrations: 
    [{
        integration_data:[]
        _id:9876
        name:"Integration 1"
        img:"Integration Logo"
    },
    {
        integration_data:[]
        _id:8765
        name:"Integration 2"
        img:"Integration Logo"
        eak:"12345678"
    }]
},
{
    _id:5555
    name:"Website2"
    wak:"567567568"
    wid:"5679"
    preview:"aSweetImage"
    cid:"679"
    integrations: 
    [{
        integration_data:[]
        _id:9877
        name:"Integration 1"
        img:"Integration Logo"
    },
    {
        integration_data:[]
        _id:8766
        name:"Integration 2"
        img:"Integration Logo"
        eak:"12345679"
    }]
}]
```

I have access to the **"_id"** for **"Website 1"** and am currently trying to call the value like this.

```
Users.find({
    eak: { "websites._id": wid, "integrations.name": "Integration 2" },
  })
    .then((eak) => {
      console.log("HERE", eak);
  })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
  });
```

I have a feeling that I am simply not fully understanding the way find() works. I have read the mongodb documentation and I am clearly missing something.

the console is logging:

```
HERE []
```

Comment: The provided domain json looks wrong.  `websites` should be an array, yet the `[]` are missing.

Comment: Thanks that was an error from where I typed it all in. I have updated.

Comment: (1) What is the output you are expecting? (2) _"... I have a feeling that I am simply not fully understanding the way find() works..."_: your feeling is correct. See the syntax and some examples in the documentation: [db.collection.find](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html).

Comment: @NathanTinius it is not possible to select only one field `eak` from nested array using `find()`, but it is possible with [aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems.

1. Mongo db us case sensitive. Searching for `website` will not result `Website` and `Website1` is not same as `website 1`
2. If your resolve the above issue, you need to use positional operator to return the matching document.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I am actually using the  _id in my Users.find() so there shouldn't be a case issue here. I am not sure I understand what you mean by 2.